# Indexing and Parsing XML files with ElasticSearch

Tags: parsing, indexing, elasticsearch, logstash

I need to index multiple XML files under multiple directories into ElasticSearch and parse them into JSON format, possibly adding some tags. Is it possible to be done with ElastichSearch and Logstash, and if so how can I do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Point logstash to your XML files and use tagging to tag different files differently to determine how they will be handled by Logstash down the road. Inside of Logstash, you can set up filters to add tags, and other fields, and in the output portion of logstash you can specify what files gets added to what index inside of elasticsearch